# Createing grid collage editor for Android. Recyclerview or Custom view

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-recyclerview

Hello I'm building app which part is collage editor. It should be based on some grid layouts but I'm not sure which way should I follow.

I need something that shutterfly has on it's iOS app:
[image]

I have 2 ideas:

1. Using RecyclerView with StraggedLayoutManager, create there some layout and do it this way.
2. Create custom View with multiple available layouts

With RecyclerView it should be easier, I need ability to swap images with dragging (animation is not needed), open editor on click on image. After clicking done I have save coordinates of every item in view to send it to API.

The number of image isn't the same every time but it can be top limit.

What do you think?